# PHP str_replace not working in my case

Tags: php

I am trying to do string replace on an array.

I have..

```
str_replace('texts', 'testssssss', $test->html);
```

The `$test->html` returns

and I want to replace all texts to testssssss..

```
key 1

<div>
   <a href='texts.company.name.html'>test</a>
</div>



Key 2

<div>
    other html...
</div>


Key 3

<div>
    other html...
</div>

Key 4

<div>
   <a href='texts.department.name.html'>department</a>
</div>

more...
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you remember to assign the output of `str_replace` to a variable?

Comment: Do you actually re-assign the return value?

Comment: You have to assign the result of the str_replace to some variable or other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign the new value somewhere, str_replace does not automatically overwrite the subject:

```
$test->html = str_replace('texts', 'testssssss', $test->html);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function returns the string so you need to start it $variable =str_replace